# User information is not displaying in user Profile

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My code doesn't displaying student name, student number, password and email. I'm retrieving data from "User" Database and I want to display the information of current user. I edit it already but nothing happens

[This is the realtime database contain invalid uid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/077zi.png)

[this is the authentication with valid uid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHhbR.png)

```
 public void showAllUserData(String pushKey) {
        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            String userKey = user.getUid();
            ref.child(userKey).child(pushKey).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    String nameString = dataSnapshot.child("userName").getValue(String.class);
                    String studNumString = dataSnapshot.child("userStudNo").getValue(String.class);
                    String emailString = dataSnapshot.child("userEmail").getValue(String.class);
                    String passString = dataSnapshot.child("userPass").getValue(String.class);

                    editname.setText(nameString);
                    editstudentNo.setText(studNumString);
                    editEmail.setText(emailString);
                    editPassword.setText(passString);
                    nameLabel.setText(nameString);
                    studentNoLabel.setText(studNumString);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    Log.e("DatabaseError", "Error reading from database: " + error.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
```

This is the Student_sign_up.java that must store valid Uid but still like in the screenshot, it produce -NUM

```
public void regUser(){
        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        reference = rootNode.getReference("User");

        String id = tx.getText().toString().trim();
        String txtName = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
        String txtStudNo = editTextStudentNo.getText().toString().trim();
        String txtEmail = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String txtPass = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();


    String userKey = auth.getUid();
        User user = new User(txtName, txtStudNo, txtEmail, txtPass, id);

        reference.child(userKey).setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Student_sign_up.this, "User Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Student_sign_in.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Student_sign_up.this, "User Failed to Register", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Step 1 is to stop ignoring potential errors and implement `onCancelled`. At its minimum that should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen , sorry. I already add it.

Comment: Good to hear.  No change in behavior then? --- If it doesn't raise an error, please change the code to log the value of `userKey` and show the updated code and its output. At that point, also show us the data from the database at `/User/$userKey ` (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes there is no changes. I add the screenshot of my database in the post.

Comment: public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    Log.e("DatabaseError", "Error reading from database: " + error.getMessage());
                } 
I change the error message, but error also is not displaying @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-NUM...` key in your screenshot is **not** a Firebase Authentication UID, but a key that was generated by calling `push()` on the database.

If you want to be able to look up the user's data by their UID, you need to **store** the data under that UID first. Typically that'd be something like:

```
ref.child(userKey).set(...);
```

You now likely have something like `ref.push().set(...)`, which generates the `-NUM` key.

---

**Update**: based on the additional code you shared, your `regUser`  needs something like this:

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    String userKey = user.getUid();
        
    reference.child(userKey).setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(Student_sign_up.this, "User Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Student_sign_in.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Student_sign_up.this, "User Failed to Register", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
}
else {
    Toast.makeText(Student_sign_up.this, "There is no current user to register", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: So i need to modify my sign up java class? I thought I stored it in uid.

Comment: You don't. If you follow the instructions from my last comment and log the `userKey` value in your code, you'll see that it outputs a different value than the `-NUM` in your JSON.

Comment: Did you initialize `userKey` there, in the same way you did in the code you shared in your question? If so, update your question to show how you write the user data *with the update* that doesn't work.

Comment: You're initializing `userKey` as a push key. I specifically asked: whether you initialized it in the same way you did in the code you shared in your question? You need something like this: `String userKey = user.getUid();` --- I added an update to show how to do this.

Comment: The code is now displaying user info thank you. But if I try to log in every account stored in database, it display a wrong info, only the first on User Node is displaying.

Comment: is get.Uid() is for authentication only, not in realtime database? Because if i`m using it to get the display of user currently log in, it always get the current/top of authentication list.

Comment: Going forward please don't make structural changes to your questions like you did to your question, as it makes it impossible for future visitors to make sense of answers to what you posted initially.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I'm didn't aware.